# How to insert rowguid and ModifiedDate in EntityFrameworkDataService

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-6, wcf-data-services

I'm using EntityFrameworkDataService in WCF service and I setup the rowguid and ModifiedData column in DB table. These values are generated by newid() and getdate() in DB. The problem is when I add new object from client application like below:

```
AddressType at = new AddressType();
at.Name = "home";

ccn.AddToAddressTypes(at);
ccn.SaveChanges();
```

It has an error. So If I add rowguid and ModifiedDate,

```
at.rowguid = Guid.NewGuid();
at.ModifiedDate = DateTime.Now;
```

It can add the object to the table. But I don't want to use the rowguid and modified value generated from the client side. I'd like to know how I have to handle the rowguid and modified value in EntityFrameworkDataService.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your model diagram (.edmx), you have to change the StoreGeneratedPattern property from "None" to "Computed". It will solve this problem. Please see the more details at http://www.ladislavmrnka.com/2011/03/the-bug-in-storegeneratedpattern-fixed-in-vs-2010-sp1/